# Storing new field to Django Admin "user" section from registration form

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

I have managed to add an additional field to the Registration form, "where did you hear about us?".

But I am not sure which files to edit in order to store the data from this field along with the users info.

i.e. When logging into the Admin section and go to "users" and view a users info I would like to see this field there.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way would be to [store additional data](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users) in a `UserProfile` model about the user, e.g.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    # This field is required.
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

    # Other fields here
    where_heard_about_us = models.TextField()
```

You can then register the object as an inline object in your Django Admin

Comment: I tried your suggestion and got the following error when going to registrations in admin. no such column: accounts_registration.where_heard_about_us

Comment: Did you do a syncdb/migrate?

Comment: Yes I did but still no luck

Comment: Assuming you're using Django >= 1.7, make sure you're doing a `manage.py makemigrations <yourapp>` first, then doing `manage.py migrate` to actually alter the database.

Comment: I am using Django 1.6.1

Comment: OK, it sounds like you're having a syncdb issue now then. The app containing the model is in your `INSTALLED_APPS`, right? Do you have more than one database? Can you share the output of the syncdb?

Comment: Yes it is in INSTALLED_APPS. `Syncing...
Creating tables ...
Installing custom SQL ...
Installing indexes ...
Installed 0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s)

Synced:
 > django.contrib.auth
 > django.contrib.contenttypes
 > django.contrib.sessions
 > django.contrib.messages
 > django.contrib.staticfiles
 > django.contrib.sites
 > pipeline
 > grappelli
 > django.contrib.admin
 > django.contrib.admindocs
 > south
 > debug_toolbar

Not synced (use migrations):
 - extras
 - photos
 - payments
 - accounts
 - shop
 - cart
 - couriers
 - lilyyoung
(use ./manage.py migrate to migrate these)`